# Chrome or bootstrap css box-shadow transition bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, less, css-transitions

I don't know how to describe the way in which this is not working, so I uploaded a screencast to you YouTube.  It is truly bizarre, and I can find nothing online that resembles this.  It only happens with the box shadow and it only happens when transitions are enabled.  It works fine with transitions and no box shadow, and it works fine with box shadow and no transitions.

**Edit**:  What I neglected to mention originally (and what I now realize was a critical part of this explanation) is that the transition-delay is 0s, and the transition-duration is 150ms.  Not necessarily important but the timing-function is ease-in-out.  The devtools computed style panel show nothing overriding any of these properties.

This

It may be a bug with my css but I can't imagine what kind of bug would produce this problem.

Check out this video for a demonstration. [Video Link on Youtube](http://youtu.be/PfctrNjnzEc)

**Note**:  This video was filmed at normal speed.

The delay between hover and transition, and the delay between button press and transition should not exist.  Does anyone know of any known "gotchas", bugs, or places to check for what might be the source of this?

*Note*:  I'm fairly certain it's not a bug with my code.  I've now checked 4 times and tested it successfully in two other browsers - also --- its a single line of uncomplicated css.  I also grepped the directory for different potential conflicts - though I'm not sure exactly what to look for.

**Edit**:  Per request.  Here is the code being used to generate the transition.

```
.navbar-nav {
    li {
        text-align: center;
        a {
                border-radius: 0;
                border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                color: #808d8e !important;
                box-shadow: 1px 12px 23px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05) inset;
                border-color: darken(@neutral-light, 9%);
                -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
                &:hover {
                    border-color: darken(@neutral-light, 15%);
                    color: @brand-primary !important;
                    box-shadow: 1px 12px 23px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1)inset, 2px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                    background-color: saturate(lighten(@neutral-light, 8%), 5%);
                }
                &:focus, &:active {
                    color: desaturate(@brand-primary, 5%);
                    background-color: saturate(lighten(@neutral-light, 4%), 0%);
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3)inset, -1px -12px 23px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2), 2px 2px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
                }
        }
    }
    li:hover + li>a {
        border-left-color: darken(@neutral-light, 15%);
    }
}
```

This is less, and compiles as you would expect.

**Additional Info and a note:** This is happening on 41.0.2222.0 canary (64-bit).

*Note*  I've discovered a strange quirk.  If I set a negative `transition-delay` the transition occurrs sort of.  But it occurrs in the following way:  Very quickly the background-color and color begin to animate, and finish, and at some point later (about the same as it has been) the box shadow comes in.  But here is the weird thing - there is a very small window where that works (something like a .2s difference), so if the duration is `.5s`, and I set the transition-delay to `-.4s`, I will see a transition somewhat normally as described above.  When dealing with 100ms transitions, the effect is obviously subtle but its still noticable.  However, if I set the duration to `.5s` and I set the delay to -`.1s`, the transition will still have that noticable visual delay.

Comment: That helps but still need some code. It's like showing us a video of your car and asking, "why can't I shift into 2nd gear". ;-)

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: @Macsupport - It's not like that.   It's more like my car won't shift into second gear - here's a video of the symptoms.  Do you have any idea why it might be doing this?  The code is basic and un-complex.  I quadruple checked the one line of code required to produce this result.  I grepped the entire directory for conflicts.  My sense is that it is a known issue or there are known "gotchas" that I missed.

Comment: @Christina.  Thanks.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: And the reason you can't post the one line of code required to produce this result? My point @Christina, is, a mechanic can't diagnose a problem from a video without actually seeing the car and one can't diagnose a code problem from a video without seeing the code.

Comment: @user1167442 - It is so much easier to get to the root of the problem if we have at least the very basic code needed to **recreate the problem**. In this case you could also recreate the problem in a [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/) copy + paste your HTML / LESS. Make it easy for us to help you and you can get results.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of any known "gotchas", bugs, or places to check for
>   what might be the source >of this?

You use the shorthand syntax to set the  transition-property(/ies) to `all`, try to replace the with the list of properties the transition effect is for.

```
transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
```

or

```
transition: box-shadow,background-color,color,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
```

`all` possible fires (undesired) [transitionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)s caught by bootstrap's jQuery plugins and also influences performance.

See: http://youtu.be/SnZaGuxvEvE

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  I'd tried that as well as writing out the properties in longhand - e.g. transition-timing-function,transition-property,transition-duration,etc.

Comment: well see: http://www.bootply.com/aO2z2m9rFv, what's the problem in the first place?

Comment: There is between a 2 and 5 delay between hover start and transition start - like you count to 5 mississippi delay.  It does happen with the bootply as well.  Is there a delay when you do it?  If not, it must be a bug with my Chrome version or something else with my computer

Comment: It looks completely normal in your video.  Did you look at my video?  There is this agonizing pause.  I'm on Version  41.0.2222.0 canary (64-bit).  It may not matter, but the comp that is testing this has a dedicated 256mb AMD Radon card, and 8gb of ram,64 bit win 7, Dual Core 3.16.  Dell XPS 420.  A little old, but certainly competent.

Comment: yes, i have seen that. unfortunately i can't help you further.